# Scala use fill or tabulate with mutable entries

Tags: scala, vector, mutable

The following generates a Vector of immutable Vectors:

```
var darr = Vector.tabulate(2, 3){ (a,b) => a*2+b }
darr: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]] = Vector(Vector(0, 1, 2), Vector(2, 3, 4))
```

But what is needed for our use case is a Vector of *mutable* Vectors.  How can that be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do nested calls to `tabulate`, where the inner call is on a mutable sequence, like `Buffer`:

```
import collection.mutable.Buffer
Vector.tabulate(2)(a => Buffer.tabulate(3)(b => a*2+b))
// Vector(ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2), ArrayBuffer(2, 3, 4))
```

The 2D `tabulate` is really just syntactic sugar for a nested `tabulate` anyway:

```
// From GenTraversableFactory
def tabulate[A](n1: Int, n2: Int)(f: (Int, Int) => A): CC[CC[A]] =
  tabulate(n1)(i1 => tabulate(n2)(f(i1, _)))
```

Comment: The exact functional recipe, using currying.

Answer (score 1):

If your collection stays the same size and all you're wanting is mutable entries, then I think using a 2D array might be a good solution. As an added bonus, the `Array` object in Scala provides `tabulate` methods for creating 1D through 5D arrays. All I had to do to get this to work was change the word `Vector` in your original example to `Array` and it works just fine:

```
scala> var darr = Array.tabulate(2, 3){ (a,b) => a*2+b }
darr: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2), Array(2, 3, 4))
```